# Filter array in sub-document array field in Spring framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, aggregation-framework, spring-mongo

I am trying to fetch an element from an array in the MongoDB in my Spring Framework project.

I have find the solution for MongoDB shell, but I do not know how to implement it by Spring.data.core.aggregation, one of aggregation operator @addFields is not supported by Spring.

Could anyone tell me how to replace this @addField or how to implement in it another way? Thank you so much!!!

MongoDB sample data:

```
{
    "_id" : 15,
    "items" : [
            {
                    "columns" : [
                            {
                                    "title" : "hhh",
                                    "value" : 10
                            },
                            {
                                    "title" : "hahaha",
                                    "value" : 20
                            }
                    ]
            },
            {
                    "columns" : [
                            {
                                    "title" : "hiii",
                                    "value" : 50
                            }
                    ]
            }
    ]
}
```

Expected result:

```
{
"_id" : 15,
"items" : [
        {
                "columns" : [
                        {
                                "title" : "hahaha",
                                "value" : 20
                        }
                ]
        },
        {
                "columns" : []
        }
]
```

}

The solution for MongoDB Shell:

```
let value = "hahaha";

db.coll.aggregate([
    {
        "$addFields": { 
            "items": { 
                "$map": { 
                    "input": "$items", 
                    "as": "item", 
                    "in": { 
                        "columns": { 
                            "$filter": { 
                                "input": "$$item.columns", 
                                "as": "elt", 
                                "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$elt.title", value ] } 
                            } 
                        }
                    }
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
])
```

MongoDB version: 3.4.1
Spring version: 1.4.3

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following but you'll need to use 1.8.5 version.

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
            project("_id").and(new AggregationExpression() {
                @Override
                public DBObject toDbObject(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {
                    DBObject filter = new BasicDBObject("input", "$$item.columns").append("as", "elt").append("cond",
                            new BasicDBObject("$eq", Arrays.<Object>asList("$$elt.title", "hahaha")));
                    DBObject map = new BasicDBObject("input", "$items").append("as", "item").append("in", filter);
                    return new BasicDBObject("$map", map);
                }
            }).as("items")
  );
```

The support for some of Mongo3.2 aggregation operators were added in 1.10.0.RC1. If you are okay with updating to release candidate version you can use the below version. I couldn't find `$addFields` stage in the RC so kept the `$project` stage.

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
            project("_id")
                    .and(mapItemsOf("items").as("item").andApply(filter("item.columns")
                            .as("elt")
                            .by(valueOf("elt.title").equalToValue("hahaha"))
                    )).as("items")
);
```

Static Imports:

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.*;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ArrayOperators.Filter.filter;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ComparisonOperators.Eq.valueOf;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.VariableOperators.mapItemsOf;
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but changing the version is too complex for me.

Comment: Spring boot 1.4.3 has spring mongo db 1.9.6 version. So first option should work for you. Did you try ?