# SpringData mongoDB API for Aggregation $map

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Following is my Native MongoDB query and below is the SpringData Mongo API equivalent. I am getting struck on using $map in $project in SpringData Mongo API. Appreciate your help on completing my conversion to API

```
db.users.aggregate([    
    { $match: {$and : [{userType:"200"} },    
     { $unwind: "$userOrgMap" },
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "users",
          localField: "userOrgMap.createdbyuser",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "created_by"
        }
   },
   {$project:{
       _id:"$_id",
       login:"$login",
       firstName:"$firstName",
       lastName:"$lastName",
       email:"$email",
       deactivateFlag:"$deactivateFlag",
       createdOn:"$createdOn",
       createdBy:{
        "$map": { 
                    "input": "$created_by", 
                    "as": "u", 
                      "in": { 
                          "name": { "$concat" : [ "$$u.firstName", " ", "$$u.lastName" ] }, 
                      } 
                }
    }
      }
    },
    { $sort : { createdBy : 1} }

])
```

Spring Query

```
 Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
            Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("userType").is(userType)),
            Aggregation.unwind("userOrgMap"),
            Aggregation.lookup("users", "userOrgMap.createdbyuser", "_id", "created_by"),
            Aggregation.project("userId","login","firstName","lastName","email","deactivateFlag","createdOn")
        );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter array in sub-document array field in Spring framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847249/filter-array-in-sub-document-array-field-in-spring-framework)

Comment: Thanks for info. But I need some more help to figure out the API  . My requirement is different. Aggregation.project("userId","login","firstName","lastName","email","deactivateFlag","createdOn")
              .and(mapItemsOf("created_by").as("u").
                ???
              )).as("createdBy")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below `$map` aggregation.

```
  project().and(mapItemsOf("created_by").
                            as("u").
                            andApply(new AggregationExpression() {
                                @Override
                                public DBObject toDbObject(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {
                                    return new BasicDBObject("name", StringOperators.valueOf("u.firstName").concat(" ").concatValueOf("u.lastName").toDbObject(aggregationOperationContext));
                                }
                            }))
             .as("createdBy");
```

Using `$let` expression

```
 project().and(VariableOperators.Let.define(VariableOperators.Let.ExpressionVariable.newVariable("u").forExpression(ArrayOperators.arrayOf("created_by").elementAt(0))).
                            andApply(new AggregationExpression() {
                                @Override
                                public DBObject toDbObject(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {
                                    return new BasicDBObject("name", StringOperators.valueOf("u.firstName").concat(" ").concatValueOf("u.lastName").toDbObject(aggregationOperationContext));
                                }
                            }))
            .as("createdBy");
```

Use lambda and static imports.

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ArrayOperators.arrayOf;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.StringOperators.valueOf;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.VariableOperators.Let.ExpressionVariable.*;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.VariableOperators.Let.define;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.VariableOperators.mapItemsOf;

project().and(mapItemsOf("created_by").
                as("u").
                andApply(aggregationOperationContext -> new BasicDBObject("name", valueOf("u.firstName").concat(" ").concatValueOf("u.lastName").toDbObject(aggregationOperationContext))))
                .as("createdBy");

    project().and(define(newVariable("u").forExpression(arrayOf("created_by").elementAt(0))).
            andApply(aggregationOperationContext -> new BasicDBObject("name", valueOf("u.firstName").concat(" ").concatValueOf("u.lastName").toDbObject(aggregationOperationContext))))
            .as("createdBy");
```

Comment: Appreciate your quick reply.But I am getting "as" as undefined

Comment: Np. Updated answer to include the `name` alias for you to use map. I can't see anything in the api to provide the alias in the nested expression. So I have utilize `BasicDBObject` to create expression. You can do this with `$let` operator too by using  `$arrayElemAt` and `$concat`.

Comment: Just realised that the result is not same for the created by. I am getting the following [{"userId":"249840105","login":"km993v","firstName":"Karthikeyan","lastName":"Maruthamuthu","createdOn":"2017-03-02 14:11:58.775","email":"abc@abc.com","deactivateFlag":false,"createdBy":"[ \"Chithra Nattamai Subburaman\"]"}]
I am expecting the following                                                     "createdBy" : [
         {
                 "name" : "kaushik Mehta"
         }
 ]

Comment: Do you mean it is missing `name` field ? from the output ? Yes, I've mentioned that in my second comment. Please use the latest code. It will work.

Comment: My requirement is to have createdBy as an additional field with the concat of firstName and lastName. I heard of addField usage in aggregation. But not sure how to use it to achieve. If having createdBy is not possible without array, I am fine. But I don't want "[ \" from the output. Because in the output , I am getting "[" as a string value and not taken as array. I would prefer to get the same output as I got for my native query. Pls help

Comment: It is an additional field. My project doesn't include other fields for clarity. The output from your native query also contains array. If you don't want array use the second solution which uses $let operator to return document.

Comment: After using $let, the result comes as "createdBy":"{ \"name\" : \"Kaushik Mehta\"}". Is it possible to get "createdBy":"Kaushik Mehta". If not possible , I am fine to sort by createdBy.name instead of createdBy. Also , Is it possible to get the value without \.

Comment: Try `project().and(define(newVariable("u").forExpression(arrayOf("created_by").elementAt(0))).andApply(valueOf("u.firstName").concat(" ").concatValueOf("u.lastName"))).as("created_by")
`

Comment: .and(VariableOperators.define(ExpressionVariable.newVariable("temp")
               .forExpression(ArrayOperators.arrayOf("created_by").elementAt(0)))
               .andApply(va‌​lueOf("temp.firstName")‌​.concat(" ").concatValueOf("temp.lastName")))
             .as("createdBy"),

Comment: Am I correct in the usage ? Also valueOf throws compilation error.

Comment: Try including the static imports from the answer.  Define should be part of let variable operators

Comment: .and(VariableOperators.define(ExpressionVariable.newVariable("temp")
               .forExpression(ArrayOperators.arrayOf("created_by").elementAt(0)))
               .andApply(StringOperators.valueOf("temp.firstName")
               .concat(" ").concatValueOf("temp.lastName")))
             .as("createdBy")

Comment: import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.VariableOperators;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ArrayOperators;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.VariableOperators.Let.ExpressionVariable;

Comment: I meant this `import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.VariableOperators.Let.define;`

Answer (score 2):

This is another approach I was able to do this.

```
Aggregation.project("userId","login","firstName","lastName","email","deactivateFlag","createdOn").and(VariableOperators.Map.itemsOf("created_by").as("u").andApply(StringOperators.Concat.valueOf("$$u.firstName").concat(" ").concatValueOf("$$u.lastName"))).as("createdBy");
```