# MongoTemplate aggregate projection, getting an exception when map array properties

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongotemplate

I have two objects and two projection objects like below,

**Main Objects**

```
public class MainItem {
    private String name;
    private List<subItem> subItems;
}


public class subItem {
    private String id;
    private String groupId;
    private String displayName;
    private Status status;
}
```

**Projection objects**

```
public class MainItemLight {
    private String name;
    private List<subItemLight> subItemList;
}


public class subItemLight {
    private String id;
    private String name;
}
```

I'm trying to map Main objects to projection objects and return a list of MainItemLight objects. Below is my code,

```
mongoTemplate.aggregate(
        newAggregation(project("name")
        .and("subItems").as("subItemList")
        .and("subItems.displayName").as("subItemList.name")
    ),
"MyCollection", MainItemLight.class).getMappedResults();
```

When I'm trying to map `subItems.displayName` to `subItemList.name` I get bellow exception,

```
Command failed with error 40176 (Location40176): 'Invalid $project 
:: caused by :: specification contains two conflicting paths. 
Cannot specify both 'subItemList.name' and 'subItemList'
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Removing `.and("subItems.displayName").as("subItemList.name")` and defining new `$project`

Comment: Like this? Still doesn't work :/
`mongoTemplate.aggregate(
        newAggregation(project("name")
        .and("subItems").as("subItemList"),
        project().and("subItems.displayName").as("subItemList.name")
    ),
"MyCollection", MainItemLight.class).getMappedResults();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      subItemList: {
        $map: {
          input: "$subItems",
          as: "item",
          in: {
            id: "$$item.id",
            name: "$$item.displayName"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/s_IzAyNdAba)

### MongoTemplate

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(project("name").and(
    VariableOperators.Map.itemsOf("subItems").as("item").andApply(
    doc -> new Document()
        .append("id", "$$item.id")
        .append("name", "$$this.displayName")
    )
).as("subItemList"));
```

Note: The `$map` implementation is not friendly in Spring Mongo, so wee need to implement it manually.

Source: [SpringData mongoDB API for Aggregation $map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43952476/springdata-mongodb-api-for-aggregation-map)

Comment: Thanks. What's the equivalent property of $map in MongoTemplate?

Comment: Thank you very much. I wasn't aware of this map functionality :)