# Mongodb Query, search array elements inside document grouping by and counting each element

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Suppose I have a collection with multiple documents with the following structure:

```
{
  _id: "id12345",
  objects: ["123","456", "789"]
}
```

Now I want to create a query where I pass an array of objects and get the count of occurrence in documents for each of the elements of the array, something like this:

input of query: `["123","321"]`
output:

```
{
  "123": 1,
  "321": 0
}
```

I want to do this just by one query, passing an array, I know I could do this easily one by one instead of an array but that is not the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation in 3.6.

[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to filter documents where there is at least one array match between input array and objects array.

[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) with [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to iterate the input array and compare with each array element in objects array and return 0 and 1 depending on the match.

[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) with [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to count the occurrences of array element across all documents.

```
db.colname.aggregate([
 {"$match":{"objects":{"$in":["123","321"]}}},
 {"$project":{
   "keyandcount":{
     "$map":{
       "input":["123","321"],
       "in":{
         "k":"$$this",
         "v":{"$cond":[{"$in":["$$this","$objects"]},1,0]}
       }
     }
   }
 }},
 {"$unwind":"$keyandcount"},
 {"$group":{"_id":"$keyandcount.k","count":{"$sum":"$keyandcount.v"}}}
])
```

You can add below two stages at the end to format the response to key value pair.

```
{"$group":{_id: null,"keycountpair":{"$mergeObjects":{"$arrayToObject":[[["$_id","$count"]]]}}}},
{"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$keycountpair"}}
```

Comment: HI @Veeram, thanks for the answer it works as expected, I need to implement this using spring data MongoDB, i know that "Aggregation" spring operation this is possible but I'm having some problems with the $map operation, using spring "mapItemsOf" function, can you give me an idea of how this should look like ?

Comment: You are welcome. I don't think you would be able to use `mapItemsOf` as it only takes field reference or aggregation expression not a static array. You need to prepare the aggregation expression. Something like `project().and(new AggregationExpression() {
                        @Override
                        public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {
                            $map code here
                        }
                    }).as("keyandcount")`

Comment: You can use the sample from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847249/filter-array-in-sub-document-array-field-in-spring-framework/41850381#41850381) and adjust to your need.

Answer (score 0):

In general the query to get this is pretty straight forward since it is not recommended to switch values to keys in the data layer but more in the presentation one.

So this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$objects"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$objects",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Would give you the numbers as `_id` and a `count` field with the number of occurrences. Then you can massage that in your app to make it look anyway you would like.

[Here is a simple example of the result](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ss5XYBkwbEm)